# About the usage of 'endless'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw a short paragraph today which is using 'endless' to describe 'features'. Could you advise me whether it is a suitable usage? It sounds strange to me. Following is the original paragraph.

> Check out the endless features included in the easy to set-up forward folding camper trailer! We've packed it with features such as a huge toolbox with two fridge slides, slide out kitchen complete with a 4 burner stove, stainless steel sink and electric tap connected to a 80L stainless steel water tank and so much more. Watch Camping Cam take you through all the inclusions of our Coorong GT package.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It's advertising hyperbole.

Comment: It suffers from the same practical problem as an invitation to "Check out the infinite space included in the Expanding Universe."

Answer (score 1):

In your example sentence, *endless* is used correctly.

Nonliteral definition of *endless*:

> Extremely numerous.

Example:

> We smoked *endless* cigarettes.

Your example sentence basically means:

> Check out the many features included in the easy to set-up forward folding camper trailer!

([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/endless)) ([Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/endless))

Comment: Hi Kyle, Thank you for the explanation and reference. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The connotation is a bit off, since endless is an analogy of time or distance, not quantity. The usage isn't technically incorrect, but Is the moral equivalent of a mixed metaphor. I would have used "innumerable".

Comment: "Endless" is a cleverer advertising term -- it suggests that you will never get to the end of the list of "features", there are so many of them.  "Innumerable", on the other hand, just provokes math anxiety.

Comment: Hi Jimm101 and Hot Licks, thank you for your answers, they are really helpful.